# SQL Query display all numbers between x and y using PHP

Tags: php, sql

Using an `html FORM` let's convert `$core` in `100` and `$mhz` in `1000` 
`emag` and `koyos` are table rows
 So if `$core` is set   `$parameters['emag'] = "$core";` is `emag=100`else it is `null`
 
`AND` and `WHERE` are dinamically setted to appear, so the problem is that I collect all data of variables in `$parameters[]` and `foreach()` them.
With my code I am get exactly what `$core` is. This is the code:

```
if (!empty($core)) {
$parameters['emag'] = "$core";

}
if (!empty($mhz)) {
$parameters['koyos'] = $mhz;
  }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE 1=1 ";
if (!empty($parameters)) {
foreach ($parameters as $k => $v) {
    $sql .= " AND " . $k . "='" . $v . "'";
}
  }
$sql .= " ORDER BY emag, performanta_cpu_core DESC, performanta_cpu DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

And it is results just rows with `emag=100`, but I have need all numbers equals or little than `100` not just `100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query conditions, based on the data you've provided, are:

`WHERE 1=1 AND emag = '100' AND koyos = '1000'`

And so obviously will only show rows where `emag` = `100`. If you want to show all those up to `100` then change `=` to `<=` when the table name is `emag`:

```
foreach ($parameters as $k => $v) {

    if ($k == 'emag')
    {
        $sql .= " AND " . $k . "<='" . $v . "'";
    }

    else
    {
        $sql .= " AND " . $k . "='" . $v . "'";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($parameters as $k => $v) {

    if ($k == 'emag') {
        $sql .= " AND " . $k . "<='" . $v . "'";
        continue;
    }

    $sql .= " AND " . $k . "='" . $v . "'";
}
```